# Transition is not smooth when pushing or poping a class

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am facing strange problem in my application. If I am using my Application in a normal way then all the things are going good and transition is smooth when going to next controller or coming from the previous one.

Problem arises when **say I launched my application and say I let my application idle for few minutes, it is active not in background then in this case the transition effect is not smooth when going to next screen or coming back to previous one. It feels like my application is going slow,Loader comes in slow motion and hides too, Navigation also seems to be slow.** Did anyone faced the same issue like me,if yes please share the solution.

Comment: Use Xcode developer Tool `Instruments` `Time Profiler` to see what happened.

Comment: Use Instruments to check for performance problems. Watch CPU and memory behavior over the inactive periods. Compare the behavior when ok and slow.

Comment: Show us codes, and check the resource usage of the App in Xcode

Comment: @Eiko my memory consumption is almost zero when app is in idle state. I don't know what to do . When App is in idle sate then how it can consume memory. I am using Nstimer for calling a function after every 30 seconds. This can create the problem??

Comment: Without code, it's hard to say. As I said: do a longterm observation with Instruments. And compare the results from different runs.

Comment: @Eiko  NSTimer was creating problem. SO I just run NSTimer code in background and everything works fine. My app is in good condition again.